# Running multiple Meteor instances out of the same bundle

Tags: linux, meteor

Say I've built a Meteor application running `meteor build` and instructed it to output to a folder with `--directory` flag.

Can I use the same directory to run multiple instances of the meteor app's server? Won't they interfere with each other?

Comment: As long as you have them running on different ports, they can live with each other. But Since their workings is of the same nature, they may interfere depending on what they are doing. Eg. Writing to db on startup

Comment: Oh, yes that kind of interference I understand. I was referring to the bundle, you know, whether meteor writes some files there which may clash or not, and things like that. Suppose that the bundle directory were read-only, would I have some issue?

Comment: What is your motive though? Do you want multiple instances for loadbalancing? Those have a better approach towards running multiple copies.

Comment: I'm using meteor-job-collection and want to run several instances of the worker application so I can run multiple jobs in parallel and take advantage of the multiple CPUs. Currently I've got one instance going to 100% easily

Comment: Hmm, this comment seems to imply "yes, you can" is the answer (or at least it was at some point)  -- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4532#issuecomment-110912016